# Avoid generic serializer for case classes under a trait in Flink

Tags: apache-flink

We have several case classes, regrouped under the same trait:

```
sealed trait Measure { ... }

case class Counter(...) extends Measure
case class Cumulative(...) extends Measure
...
```

A large part of our Flink topology is based on `DataStream[Measure]`, and Flink falls back to generic Kryo serialization, and I understand this should be avoided.

Following the [doc](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.12/dev/types_serialization.html#most-frequent-issues), I tried to register the leaf types in the ExecutionEnv, but it seems it still uses the generic Kryo serializer (seen using a debugger).

What's the proper way to force Flink to use its native fast case class serializers for all leaf classes ?

PS: We're using Flink 1.12

Comment: This looks interesting: https://index.scala-lang.org/findify/flink-adt/flink-adt/0.2.3?target=_2.12. Or you could just implement your own serializer and register it with Kryo to use your own custom serialization.

Comment: How do you register the type?